# Is it possible to set a background color for the icon in the notification drawer on Android if using Parse Push?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Is it possibile to change the background color for the icon in the notification in the notification drawer on Android if using Parse Push?

I'm talking about the background color for the circle you can take a look at from the image below

Thanks in advance,

Adriano

[image: Notifications in the notification drawer]

Answer (score 22):

I think you can use the following method:

1. Implement a custom `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`
2. Override `getNotification(Context context, Intent intent)`
3. Set notification color

Here's an example of how I did it:

```
public class PushBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Notification notification = super.getNotification(context, intent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            notification.color = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.your_background_color);
        }
        return notification;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Get bitmap of your image that you wants to set as icon to notification.

```
Canvas canvas =  new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawColor(bgcolor);
```

And set bitmap to your notification builder.

```
notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
```